# How to create a bi-directional connection between svelte-headless-table and svelte-gantt

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store

I want the user to be able to select/filter data in [svelte-headless-table](https://github.com/bryanmylee/svelte-headless-table) and then the  [svelte-gantt](https://github.com/ANovokmet/svelte-gantt)-component should show matching data based on the previous selections. Furthermore, changes (e.g. by moving the blocks) should also be synchronized back into the table.

I'm looking for a good way to archive this bi-directional connection.

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Comment: I didn't really know where to start, because of svelte-headless-tables' extensive use of stores. I'm looking for a general direction what I can try. My inital thougts where to use the headless-table stores.